# How to make a docker image with Anaconda and be able to use GPU?

Tags: docker, anaconda, gpu

I have a GPU, and CUDA driver installed. I am making a docker image using the official anaconda image available at docker hub. When I use the command nvidia-smi inside the docker image, it shows there is no CUDA DRIVER installed.

How should I make a docker image to be able to use Anaconda with GPU?

Answer (score 2):

Docker 19.03 has native support for NVIDIA GPUs. Install `nvidia-container-runtime` and use the `docker run --gpus all` flag with your Anaconda container. Remember, that you can run Windows containers with GPU acceleration on a Windows host using Docker 19.03, but not a Linux container.

Source: [GPU Acceleration in Windows Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/gpu-acceleration)

Comment: that's what i m worried about ... i have win10 as base and inside my docker image is ubuntu and flask app  - how to make it work ?

Comment: could u help with similar question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600436/nvidia-driver-support-on-ubuntu-in-docker-from-host-windows-found-no-nvidia-d